# Copying from SQL Server table to Oracle 11g using ssis

Tags: sql-server, oracle11g, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, msbi

I'm copying huge amount of data (4-30M rows) from SQL Server (ole db source) to Oracle database (ado.net destination) using SSIS. It takes more than 4 hours to transfer.

Can anyone help me to more quickly transfer from a SQL Server table to Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing  `defaultBufferMaxRows` to an extremely large number. See other performance troubleshooting ideas here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/data-flow-performance-features?view=sql-server-ver15